# Ubuntu 13.04 Mouse settings don't affect my mouse?

Tags: mouse, settings, xinput

I have a Razer Deathadder mouse. I haven't installed any drivers for it or anything yet. Do I need to? The mouse sensitivity settings don't have any effect on my mouse. The `xinput` settings do however. The whole reason I'm looking into this is I want to turn off mouse acceleration, which I've seen many answers for. Also the mouse sensitivity settings in StarCraft II (I'm using wine) don't work either.

I have used:

```
xinput set-prop 11 265 -1 #acceleration profile. Default is 0
xinput set-prop 11 266 1 #constant deceleration, I have tried settings between 1 and 2, higher is slower
xinput set-prop 11 268 1 #velocity scaling, this doesn't seem to do anything noticable. Default is 10
xset m 0 0 #not sure what this is...
```

in several combinations.

I have used the `razercfg` tool before with Ubuntu 12.04. It slowed down my mouse when I was having the problem of it being super fast (I don't have that issue in 13.04). Other than that it didn't do a whole lot, other than let me configure LEDs.

Comment: http://bues.ch/cms/hacking/razercfg.html seems to be it.  If that doesn't work for you, you are most likely out of luck.  Hardware manufacturers generally do not support linux or release source for their drivers, meaning drivers not based on an open standard must be reverse engineered.  Anyone doing work along these lines for this device will know about razorcfg and have noted that (from the homepage) "If you want support for any other Razer mouse and you are a software developer..." they can get involved with that.  So again, if that doesn't do it, there probably isn't anything.

Comment: Do the `xinput` commands do what you want? I'm not sure who handles the mouse under wine, it might be windows.

Comment: @terdon the acceleration profile is one of those ones that is hard to tell if it's working or not. It seems to change it, but it doesn't feel like a mouse I'm using in windows with the acceleration turned off there. the constant deceleration works but you cant go below 1, and my intuition says this is USING acceleration, which I want to do away with in the first place.

Comment: I installed razercfg, and now mouse acceleration is blatantly obvious and slightly irritating.

Comment: This might be relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90585/

Comment: Yes I've played with all the settings in `xinput`. Also I just discovered that when I run `qrazercfg` which is the GUI version of razercfg, my `xinput` settings reset. Are they conflicting?