# Mouse pointer moves on its own

Tags: hardware, mouse

When I leave the mouse *(Logitech Performance Mouse MX)* alone, it moves (somewhat continuously) ever so slightly on its own! This causes several issues:

- when watching a video full screen, the seek bar at the bottom never closes
- screensaver/monitor sleep never activates

I'm running Debian Testing and the issue has been persisting for months now, so I assume it's something that is wrong with my setup (maybe I lack some essential packages?)

PS: I checked, there is no such issue on Windows, so it's not the mouse surface or something wrong with the mouse.

PPS: I've also tried [solaar](https://github.com/pwr/Solaar), but didn't help.

Comment: I sometimes have similar problems under Linux. I suppose that the Windows driver discards small moves. I wonder whether this can be done under Linux. Ditto for the mouse wheel, which is too sensitive with some mice.

Comment: Obvious question, but do you have this problem with a different mouse?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I don't know. I don't have another mouse.

Comment: I had this issue once and it turned out to be bad hardware.

Comment: Are you using the Touchscreen or it's configuration in Xorg ?
Please provide your xorg.conf

Comment: http://paste.debian.net/?show=115629;lines=0

Comment: Have you fixed this? If not, did you try [changing the mouse sensitivity](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90572/how-can-i-set-mouse-sensitivity-not-just-mouse-acceleration) with `xinput`, and changing mouse acceleration with `xset m`? Maybe you could turn the sensitivity way down with `xinput`, and then use acceleration to turn it back up again (maybe something like `xset m 100 1`), leaving a dead spot of a couple pixels.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but is your laptop's cover down while this happens? It's a silly question, I know, but I noticed this behavior myself not too long ago. Doing *cat /dev/input/mice* started printing a bunch of garbled crap on my screen. I was about to start thinking about buying a new mouse, when I lifted my laptop's cover and voila, it stopped. My laptop doesn't go into standby when it goes down, so I kept it down because I have it attached to a monitor. But seems like the touchpad might be taking signals from the screen, causing the pointer to move. Just worth mentioning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually run `tail -f` on your mouse device file, this may change among kernels and distros but it should show you if your mouse is sending some irrelevant signals when it's not supposed to or vice versa.

The device file might be at the following location:

`/dev/input/mice` (Some tutorials confirm that this is the actual location of the file in Debian).

If you guys are aware of any other locations don't hesitate.

This file is not very comprehensible by humans and yet it's the only way to actually see the calls performed by your hardware.

Another possible option is to use the `xev` tool (bundled with some popular distros but you can install it if needed) which can read this rubbish coming from your `/dev/input/mice` file and show you the coordinates for example.

Comment: I'm running Fedora 20 and `tail -f /dev/input/mice` doesn't print anything.

Comment: Yeah, that was the answer for Debian, on Red Hat based distros you better try `/dev/input/mouse0`

Comment: That seems to work, so +1 from me.

Comment: there is `/dev/input/mice` but running `tail -f /dev/input/mice` doesn't print anything.

Comment: Yes, I've actually experienced the same with my Arch, try using `cat` instead of `tail -f`

Comment: okay. i've run `cat /dev/input/mice` and it spits out garbled chars. when the mouse pointer moves by itself it show one char. but how does this help me? i already know that the mouse moves by itself.

Comment: Plain simple, if the mouse moves while the garbled chars does not appear it's not a hardware issue, if the garbled characters keep appearing even when you don't move the mouse then you should replace the mouse.