# Mouse movement speed is set to max, but still slow

Tags: mouse

Using Ubuntu 14.04/GNOME, we set the mouse move speed to max in the menu.

But the mouse movement is still slow on the touchpad.

A USB mouse is perfect, but we need to use the touchpad.

**Question:** Is there a way to speed up the touchpad?

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/205676/how-to-change-mouse-speed-sensitivity or http://askubuntu.com/questions/172972/configure-mouse-speed-not-pointer-acceleration

Comment: Have you tried increasing the acceleration?  Sometimes that's a separate slider.  Otherwise there may be hardware settings in your bios (assuming you're using a laptop's built-in touchpad).

Comment: This solved it for me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177640

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one...

```
gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

If you have no xorg.conf file create an empty one. Add something similar to this and play around with the parameters.

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier         "Touchpad"
    Driver             "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad    "on"
    Option         "VertTwoFingerScroll" "on"
    Option         "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "on"
    Option         "VertScrollDelta" "85"
    Option         "HorizScrollDelta" "85"
    Option         "TapButton1" "0"
    Option         "TapButton2" "0"
    Option         "TapButton3" "0"
    Option         "MinSpeed"   "0.7"
    Option         "MaxSpeed"   "1.4"
    Option         "AccelFactor"   "0.1"
EndSection
```

You can test Options for your current session with synclient. This way you don't have to restart X for the changes to take effect. Once you are happy with the parameters you can add/edit/remove them to your xorg.conf to make them permanent.

```
$ sudo apt-get install synclient
```

temporarily enable SHMConfig

```
$ synclient SHMConfig=1
```

test options. for example MinSpeed

> $ synclient MinSpeed=0.5

for a detailed list of options and their values run

```
$ man synaptics
```

press j to scroll down

press k to scroll up

press / to search for a string, press n for next match, p for previous match

press ? for reverse search

press q to quit