# Increase mouse speed (xinput)

Tags: x11, mouse, xinput

I don't know how to increase mouse speed.
Some weeks ago `xset` was working fine.
Now, I increase speed using command

```
xinput --set-prop 'USB OPTICAL MOUSE' 'libinput Accel Speed' 1
```

But it isn't enough for me. List of options available on mouse:

```
Device 'USB OPTICAL MOUSE':
    Device Enabled (152):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (154): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed (288):     1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (289):     0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (290):        1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (291):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (292):   1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (293):       0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (294):       0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (273):     1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (274):        0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (275):        0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (295):     0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (296):     0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (297):        0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (298):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (299):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (300): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (301): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (302):        0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (303):        0
    Device Node (276):      "/dev/input/event2"
    Device Product ID (277):        2362, 9505
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (304):       <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (305):       1
```

I'm using X, not Wayland.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I need to apply transform matrix:

```
 xinput --set-prop 'USB OPTICAL MOUSE' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 1.5
```

More details here: [How can I set mouse sensitivity, not just mouse acceleration?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90572/how-can-i-set-mouse-sensitivity-not-just-mouse-acceleration?rq=1)