# Identify a specific mouse using xinput to process an xinput command

Tags: x11, xorg, mouse, xinput, libinput

Using Manjaro 23.0, I found a way to decrease the speed of my USB SteelSeries mouse but I struggle to make it persistent. After some time being not in use, or a system reboot, the xinput settings reset to the "default". The mouse gets a new "Id" evertime at least anytime I reboot. This problem should be solved with the xorg.conf code I found below. Otherwise I have to find the mouse Id via xinput manually.

These are the xinput settings I would like the mouse to run on the my new xorg.conf:

```
$ id="10"; speed=0.23; xinput set-prop $id "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" $speed, 0, 0, 0, $speed 0, 0, 0, 1
```

Via [keep xinput settings after mouse wakeup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/620642/keep-xinput-settings-after-mouse-wakeup) I found out how to do this but not how to translate my settings from xinput to X11. Unfortunately the name of most (if not all) options of libinput differs between xinput and xorg.conf.

Here is the xorg.conf code I want to use:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "My Mouse"
    MatchProduct "SteelSeries SteelSeries Rival 300 Gaming Mouse"
    Option "TransformationMatrix" "????"
EndSection
```

Is there maybe a command I could use to transform my xinput cli setting that would achieve the goal?

Comment: Was my question too complicated or otherwise incorrectly asked? I can change it or bring more details if necessary.

Comment: According to the [xorg.conf man](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml) it's `Option "TransformationMatrix" "a b c d e f g h i"` so in your case that'd be `Option "TransformationMatrix" "0.23 0 0 0 0.23 0 0 0 1"`

Comment: It worked! Thank you @don_crissti Maybe use it as answer so I can tag it as solved?!